# Solving a system of equations, based on a gear, such that solutions are natural numbers or proving no solution exists.

Tags: systems-of-equations, natural-numbers

I'm not sure how to exactly ask this question. I'm essentially looking for a way to solve a set of natural numbers from a set of equation based on a gear. In addition I'm looking for a way to prove if there such a set exists. And if it does not is there an easy way to find a set of numbers, restricted to X decimal places, that exits to fit the equation system?

My question is based on gears and requires to solve a system of equation. If there is a gear with ***N*** number of teeth, a outer/tip diameter $ \mathbf{\phi_{tip}} $, a inner/root diameter $ \mathbf{\phi_{root}} $, and the linear distance ***d*** between each tooth along the outer diameter. There are two images below. In the second image the pitch if moved to the tips of the teeth would be the representation of the distance d.

The restriction/problem is to find a solution or set of solution such that $ \mathbf{ N, \phi_{tip}, \phi_{root}, d} \in \Bbb N $, or prove it is impossible for such a set to exist.

[image] [image]

The equation to form a system are:

$$ \phi_{ref} = Nm $$
$$ \phi_{tip} = \phi_{ref} + 2m $$
$$ \phi_{root} = \phi_{ref} - 2.5m $$
$$ d = \sqrt{2r^2\left(1-\cos \left( \frac{360^\circ}{N} \right)\right)} $$

In the last equation ***r*** is the radius of the tip diameter. The ***m*** is any real non-negative and non zero number.

Thank you in advanced.

[Here](https://khkgears.net/new/gear_knowledge/abcs_of_gears-b/basic_gear_terminology_calculation.html) is a link contain an explanation for gears, also the place the picture was taken from.

Comment: Why $+2m$ and $-2.5m$ ??

Comment: IMO this does not make much sense. If $\phi$ and $d$ are integer numbers of mm, they won't be integer in inches.

Comment: Is $d$ a *linear* or *circular* distance ? (linear seems odd)

Comment: @YvesDaoust The +2m and -2.5m in the two equations are as a formulae. Similar to F=ma, here they are used to determine the actually size of the gear; however working backwards from a diameter of the gear we get the module m. However, I'm not sure why mathematically they are there. Hope that helps.

Comment: The reason for a linear distance d is if you would use a compass to make a gear, marking down each tooth. Rather than marking each tooth using a protractor. hence, the linear distance. That is a good point about the units, I would say the mathematician should pick them or leave them as algebraic from with "units". @YvesDaoust

Comment: I guess that this is not possible, due to Niven's theorem.

Comment: Never before heard of Niven's theorem. From my understanding it states that there are only a set of values of feta that are rational that give out a rational value. For cos these values are 0, 0.5, and 1. Ignoring negatives since $N$ cannot be negative. Then 0 and 1 also fail due to giving a value of $d$ as 0. Hence, for me $cos(\frac{360\deg}{N})=1/2 $, $ N = 6 $. So, the diameters will be: $ \phi_{root}=7$, $ \phi_{tip} = 16 $, and $d = \phi_{tip}/2 = 8 $

Comment: You got it Wojciech.

Comment: No, wait. I just physically checked it. There was an error. The equation for $d$ is $d = \sqrt{2r^2-2rcos\left(\frac{360\deg}{N}\right)}$ using the same logic you can get a polynomial for $d$ for which the answer is never an natural number. You were right. It is impossible.